# Solve the equation $1+2^x+2^{x+y}=(1+2^n)^z$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, diophantine-equations

For fixed integer $n$ solve the equation $1+2^x+2^{x+y}=(1+2^n)^z$ for integers $x,y,z.$.

It is easy to find two   solutions: $z=1,x=n-1,y=0$  and $z=2,x=n+1,y=n-1.$
How to prove that there are not any solution for $z>2?$

Comment: What if you binomial expand the RHS?

Comment: I got $\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{z}{i} 2^{zi} $

Comment: The upper bound for the summation ought to be z as well. Additionally, the LHS is a number with 3 non-zero digits in base 2 (ie, 1000101 or 10101). The RHS, though, is going to have more than that unless there's some kind of combination of terms going on. Try to show that there will be more than 3 non-zero digits, regardless of how the terms combine. (Of course, this is just off the top of my head...I don't know for certain if that leads to a solution)

Comment: It is not clear for me that RHS in base 2 has  more that 3 non-zero digits

Comment: The RHS has z+1 terms to add as you see in the binomial expansion, meaning that you could have up to z+1 non-zero digits (and up to (n+1)*z digits total). The catch is if enough of those z+1 terms combine to fight the form on the left, which I would think highly unlikely. But again, I'm not sure I'm sending you down the right path here...I'm attempting a solution in this fashion but having trouble. Just food for thought.

Comment: So, here's another solution: z=4, n=1, x=5, y=2.

Comment: $x=4$ but thanks anyway

Comment: Perhaps modular arithmetic coupled with Fermat's Little Theorem